# creating a stored procedure in OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, ado.net

when i try to add stored procedure to access Database, I don't find the option 'Add'[image]

Comment: Did you click the arrow or you right click to "Stored Procedure" text? Maybe your user doesn't have a permission for them?

Comment: Attached image not display, and also your question is not clear. can you explain little bit more.